# Let $x,$ $y,$ and $z$ be nonnegative real numbers such that $x + y + z = 5.$ Find the maximum value of...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let $x,$ $y,$ and $z$ be nonnegative real numbers such that $x + y + z = 5.$ Find the maximum value of
>   $$\sqrt{2x + 1} + \sqrt{2y + 1} + \sqrt{2z + 1}.$$

---

I do not know how to approach this problem. Can anyone give me a hint?

Thanks!

Comment: Using the equality, you can plug-in one of the variables and end up with a two-variable function and embed the information contained in the equality in this new function. Notice that square root is a concave function and hence as a linear combination of concave functions, so is this one. How can you use concavity of the function to find its maximizer?

Comment: @Bob Robert I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: It's symmetric, so take $x=y=z$

Comment: @J. W. Tanner Are you sure? There is the following problem for you. Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be non-negative numbers such that $a+b+c=3$. Find a maximal value of $\prod\limits_{cyc}(a^2-ab+b^2).$ Good luck! Try $(a,b,c)=(2,1,0)$ before.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg where did you get this wonderful counter-example?

Comment: Are you supposed to know about Lagrange multipliers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I managed to work it out. This is actually almost a direct application of the QM-AM Inequality. This inequality for a set of numbers $\{a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n\}$ is,
$$\sqrt{\frac{a_1^2 + a_2^2+\dots+a_n^2}{n}}\geq\frac{a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_n}{n}.$$
Using this inequality on the numbers $\{\sqrt{2x+1},\sqrt{2y+1},\sqrt{2z+1}\}$, we get, 
$$\sqrt{\frac{(2x+1)+(2y+1)+(2z+1)}{3}}\geq\frac{\sqrt{2x+1} + \sqrt{2y+1} + \sqrt{2z+1}}{3}.$$
We can multiply both sides by $3$ and rearrange to get, 
$$\sqrt{3\cdot(2\cdot(x+y+z)+3)}\geq \sqrt{2x+1} + \sqrt{2y+1} + \sqrt{2z+1},$$
which simplifies to,
$$\sqrt{39}\geq \sqrt{2x+1} + \sqrt{2y+1} + \sqrt{2z+1}.$$
This means that $\sqrt{2x+1} + \sqrt{2y+1} + \sqrt{2z+1}$ is definitely smaller than $\sqrt{39}$, but we still need to show that equality occurs. We find that equality occurs for $x=y=z=\frac{5}{3}$, which means our answer is $\boxed{\sqrt{39}}.$